# Confusion about modifying NSMutableArray contents after using addObject:

Tags: objective-c, macos

So, when I modify things inside of an NSMutableArray I don't get the result I expect. I think the best way to frame this question is with an example. The following code prints "george" (as expected):

```
NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sally",@"george", nil];
    NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [secondArray addObject:originalArray[1]];

    secondArray[0] = @"priscilla";

    NSLog(@"%@",originalArray[1]);
```

But this code prints "priscilla":

```
    TestClass *test1 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    test1.clientName = @"sally";

    TestClass *test2 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
    test2.clientName = @"george";

    NSMutableArray *originalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:test1,test2, nil];
    NSMutableArray *secondArray =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [secondArray addObject:originalArray[1]];

    TestClass *objectTakenFromSecondArray = secondArray[0];

    objectTakenFromSecondArray.clientName = @"priscilla";

    NSLog(@"%@", ((TestClass *)originalArray[1]).clientName);
```

I thought that addObject: always copied the object before adding it to the array receiving the addObject: message. Is this not the case?

Thanks!

p.s. here is the interface and implementation for TestClass in case it is pertinent:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *clientName;
@end

@implementation TestClass
@synthesize clientName = _clientName
@end
```

Comment: `addObject` *never* copies the object.  What would make you think otherwise?

Comment: That code would crash immediately. originalArray only has two objects, so originalArray [2] will crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much answered your own question.  When you create an NSMutableArray and add an object to it, you are just creating a pointer to that object, wherever it is stored.  If you add the same object to another NSMutableArray, that too contains a pointer to the same thing.  You might not need the analogy, but for anyone else confused - the NSMutableArray is like a postman with an address to post to, and the object is the house at that address.  Two postmen (or two arrays) can have an address for the same house, but there is only one house still.  (That is, unless someone explicitly 'copies' the house).

So in your second to last line of code, where you change that .clientName property, you are changing the property of the original *test2 object.

Worth noting in this case, that if you remove that second array, you don't remove the objects it contains necessarily.  So in your case, removing that second NSMutableArray from memory does not mean that all of its objects also disappear from memory - unless everything else that points to those objects also is removed.  The array does not contain pointers to unique copy of those objects - it just points to the originals.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that addObject: always copied the object before adding it to the array receiving the addObject: message. Is this not the case?

`addObject:` does not copy the object. `NSArray` does not require that its contents even be copyable (not everything is). That probably explains the confusion. If you want to copy it, you need to do so yourself.